# HTTPS makes my pages work incorrectly and HTTP makes my page works correctly

Tags: php, html, http, https

I created a page and when I uploaded it to the server I noticed that when using `https` the font changes and imput search field gets hidden. Why is that?

Without HTTPS:

[image: NoHTTPS]

With HTTPS:

[image: WithHTTPS]

Comment: We would need to see the code to be sure but I would guess you qualified the CSS/fonts and maybe the javascript links with `http` and now it wont load them

Comment: A link to the web page would be helpful. Also, what does the developer console say? If you import a font with an `http` link to an `https` web page it could be that the import is prevented for security reasons.

Comment: @RiggsFolly @Aaron3219 you were both right, I was importing JS files and font as `http` instead of `https`.